# Catching window creation message when application is launched

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to intercept the message that is sent to create a window when an application is launched. I want to catch this message, and somehow save it and then send it back out 10 seconds later.

So basically I can intercept the message before it creates the application window and then send it back out myself.

The purpose isn't to add 10 second delay on the application, I am just trying to learn the messaging system a little more(how to catch a msg and send it out myself.) I am just unsure what I need to filter to catch the window creation of another application and how to store the message so I can send it back out. I don't wan't it to delay the whole process from being launched, just window creation.

My application listens for notepad being launched

My application captures the message to create the window

My application stores the message and delays window creation 5-10 seconds

My application sends message back out and notepad window is created.

Can anyone help me out a little with accomplishing this? I have no problem with trying to do this in C#, vb.net or C++. So any help would be great.

Comment: I have no idea how to safely/reliably implement any of the four steps you outline.  The whole idea sounds extremely dodgy.

Comment: Well I know how to filter messages and send them back out,  I am mainly having issues on what exactly I need to catch for the initial window creation/paint and how to store the message.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for actually exists in windows, it is referred to as "hooking" (no relation to ladies of the evening). It is all native win32 code. Here is an old article (11 years ago!) that hits the highlights http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed.

Hooking is hard to use, but if you master it you will have learned lots in the process. This is also great stuff for writing trojans viruses, etc. which is why it requires elevated elevated privileges to use. Without checking, newer versions of Windows may have locked out some of the things the articles mentioned, but if you have full rights, I suspect most or all of it still works.

If you are really just interested in learning how messaging really works, you do not really need to dig into hooking. Learn to using the Spy32 (or equivalent), and override the message handlers in some learning executables that write messages back and forth to each other and you will know more about windows than just about everyone else.